# Jupyter Notebook 500 internal server error after switching default browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I used to use Safari to access my jupyter notebook. I just changed the default browser to Chrome and tried to access my notebooks as usual. However, I met this problem when opening the notebooks I want.

I am using the anaconda navigator to connect to the notebook. I have attached the application launch error below. Much appreciated!

```
[I 13:37:52.979 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/Jackey/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[W 13:37:52.981 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
[I 13:37:52.987 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/Jackey/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 13:37:52.987 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/Jackey/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 13:37:52.988 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/Jackey
[I 13:37:52.988 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 13:37:52.988 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=dcebce9007f64ca40263b91284dc1861092be4a8e193933b
[I 13:37:52.988 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:37:53.006 LabApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///Users/Jackey/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1014-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8888/?token=dcebce9007f64ca40263b91284dc1861092be4a8e193933b
[W 13:37:55.460 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
[E 13:37:59.274 LabApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents/Documents?content=1&1581187079269 (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/contents/Documents?content=1&1581187079269', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Jackey/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
result = await result
File "/Users/Jackey/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "/Users/Jackey/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
File "/Users/Jackey/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 431, in get
model = self._dir_model(path, content=content)
File "/Users/Jackey/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 313, in _dir_model
for name in os.listdir(os_dir):
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/Jackey/Documents'
[W 13:37:59.282 LabApp] Unhandled error
[E 13:37:59.283 LabApp] {
"Host": "localhost:8888",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Authorization": "token dcebce9007f64ca40263b91284dc1861092be4a8e193933b",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.5",
"Cookie": "_xsrf=2|95387f6b|9a3d1000c90ed9a65471ea2ed6b49389|1581180253; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1581180545|23:username-localhost-8889|44:N2I5MzVkMzc1N2QyNDJlNmFkMmVmYTgxOGY1ZTlhZDE=|d33e2936b447bc934ec13a48958ccd10145de79116ec22fabb6928747b3a6e63\"; username-localhost-8890=\"2|1:0|10:1581181126|23:username-localhost-8890|44:M2RmN2FkNTAzZWYxNDBjOGE5ODE5OWQ2YWFiMmQ5NTI=|aa3d89f15f3b846dc92526621bafae58152bd2953083c29345241a365c5d5db1\"; username-localhost-8882=\"2|1:0|10:1581183198|23:username-localhost-8882|44:YjdiZDcwMWVlNWQzNDQwOGFlYjg4ZDlkYjRjMmZhMzQ=|230f9bd09f40a5ed68ab6c51e20326bfa3dd838e83e10e8227d914016a0946fa\"; username-localhost-8830=\"2|1:0|10:1581183500|23:username-localhost-8830|44:YjJiMjAwODQwOTI2NDE0Yzg5MGMwNGJlZThlMDMzY2Q=|e7d154db5e23bb2ed90a3d870f26f6d7ae2ecded5964b2a4fcbd0612c54ebdd8\"; username-localhost-8867=\"2|1:0|10:1581183684|23:username-localhost-8867|44:Mzg0ZGNhMzliZGI1NDRiZDk3ZjYxZjRmZDQ0NzVlNGY=|eee7163b622b9762027f53614ed4256182298b9ee98c14d7adffdb4cd905aae3\"; username-localhost-8841=\"2|1:0|10:1581183708|23:username-localhost-8841|44:YWViOWMzZDdmMmI3NDNlZWJiNmE3YmIwOTdkYmIxNDg=|90d6d11919de18c13f97f1d1f71996956800498a7e5e0636231fbd3acc288122\"; username-localhost-8973=\"2|1:0|10:1581184155|23:username-localhost-8973|44:Y2IxZmQ4ZDBkNzhlNGJkZDhmOTZmYjQ5NTcwZGMxODQ=|ffaccfb0d77e0818c67e62ed7c0b1ab40c21df6cbf1f817be02d5365d8db7aa4\"; username-localhost-8885=\"2|1:0|10:1581184821|23:username-localhost-8885|44:NmVjYjY1MjkxYzdiNDUxNTg0MTA1OTQ3NThlZmIyYTQ=|e14eecd3da726f5c007e3a9e29acb210d247926116b97dbf7c0c3faac9062f74\"; username-localhost-8901=\"2|1:0|10:1581185306|23:username-localhost-8901|44:OWM0YjUyMWNkY2YxNDFiZjhmMDAyZGVjNDYxN2NjYTA=|84bfa6e5a175e0b3370efeac634bea39607228e05ea205f706b229f67dc85085\"; username-localhost-8800=\"2|1:0|10:1581185735|23:username-localhost-8800|44:N2NjZjRjMmEzNjY4NDkwY2E1N2JjNDQ5MTRjZGRlMzc=|62e33da6e4670fed7a5ac30f679f8cbe96e36a6fed0031fb2776b8b570718c6b\"; username-localhost-8981=\"2|1:0|10:1581185860|23:username-localhost-8981|44:MjgzMGIzYTJkNGVkNDM4ZTk2Mjg0Njg3YzIyZDYyN2Q=|9930847d432ce3e2dbf40e16ab9f94bc367e49133a48ecbfe8da0833bb131e95\"; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1581187077|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MTQ2YjYyOWVhMTMxNDdkZDk2MmQyYTQxZjVkM2RjMjI=|b9d6988d5147abb50f86322c780e45afb19b57cd2d158b85fd4ff6be2abae944\""
}
[E 13:37:59.283 LabApp] 500 GET /api/contents/Documents?content=1&1581187079269 (::1) 10.02ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
```

Comment: It looks like browser specific configurations are cached.  Did you run `jupyter notebook --browser any`?  Either way, I'd try re-starting the kernel.

Comment: Yes. I have run ```jupyter notebook --browser chrome```. The notebook itself worked fine. However, it is a little different from the page I am familiar with. By opening notebooks through anaconda navigator I will have the notebook and the file browsing system open on the left of the screen, which I found very handy. Do you know how I can get the file browsing tool back?